# Time complexity in ascending order

Tags: performance, time-complexity, runtime-compilation

What is the ascending order of growth rate of the following functions:

1. 2^((logn)^1/2)
2. 2^n
3. 2^(n/2)
4. n^(4/3)
5. n(logn)^3
6. n^logn
7. 2^(n^2)
8. n!

   log n is with base 2.

Comment: Have you ever used an online service for [function plotting](http://www.fooplot.com)?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog....read the full question the base 2 is mentioned.

Comment: @RAFA apologies. comment retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We can immediate deduce that `n!` is the highest order, as it is equal to

  [image]

  ... and the `n^n` part far exceeds any of the other functions.
- Since

  [image]

  We can deduce that (1) is less than other functions with `n` as the base, e.g. (4), (5) and (6). In fact it is less than *all* of the other functions.
- (3) < (2), since the latter is the former squared.
- (2) < (7), since the latter is the former to the power `n`.
- (4) < (6), since `log n > 4/3`.
- From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial), `log n` grows more slowly than *any positive power of* `n`. Therefore:

  [image]

  Thus (5) < (4), (6)
- Using a logarithm law transformation we obtain the following:

  [image]

  Thus (6) < (3).

---

Compiling all of the reasoning steps above, we deduce the ascending order to be:

> **(1).** [image]
>
> **(5).** [image]
>
> **(4).** [image]
>
> **(6).** [image]
>
> **(3).** [image]
>
> **(2).** [image]
>
> **(7).** [image]
>
> **(8).** [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...Your efforts are really appreciable.